# Moving of a particular file

Tags: unix

1st I need to check the File system usage of a folder(i.e test/CBIS),

if it's greater than 30 then move the particular file `(i.e CBIS*)` to some other folder(Test1/CBIS/archive).

Comment: 0) You need to indicate what you've done and where you got stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `du -sg *` this will give the file system usage of all folders and files in the current directory. You can replace the `*` with file anem or folder name.

you can use `mv <source> <target>` to move the file/folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that looks impressive. can you please write it in a script so that it can be automated.